# Is there a possibility to remap Heroku PORT environment variable to another name?

Tags: heroku

I need to deploy an existing web application to Heroku using Docker and it expects the port to be passed as `APPNAME_PORT` and not `PORT`.

I know I can rebuild the Docker image to do the mapping internally, but it will be annoying to do as I'll need to have the altered Dockerfile I need to update the application. Is there a possibility to remap the environment variable to another name within Heroku?

Is there a way to do something like `APPNAME_PORT=$PORT` in Config Vars to store the `PORT` name into `APPNAME_PORT` environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Heroku support:

> I'm afraid there's no native feature to alias config vars - you can do this for add-ons via the `-as` flag with the `addons:attach` command but that's only for add-ons which are irrelevant here. You would need to alias the port in your code.